# ZFS SSD pool - Postgres setup really slow for large table ALTER command Write operations)

Tags: postgresql, performance, zfs, solid-state-drive

We recently moved a db(1.2TB) cluster from mirrored SSD to ZFS pool build-up of SSD. After the move, I have seen a massive drop in performance on large write operations (Alter table types, vacuums, index creation etc.).

To Isolate the problem I did the following, copied the 361 GB table and ensured no triggers are active, try to run the following command, original type as timestamp

```
ALTER TABLE table_log_test ALTER COLUMN date_executed TYPE timestamptz;
```

This takes about 3 hours to complete, make sense it needs to touch every one of the 60 mil rows, however, this takes about 10 min on the test system only on SSD

Comparing the alter commands **zpool iostat** outputs to **fio** I get the following results

Alter command

```
pool        alloc   free   read  write   read  write
----------  -----  -----  -----  -----  -----  -----
tank        1.33T  5.65T  6.78K  5.71K  31.9M   191M
  raidz1    1.33T  5.65T  6.78K  5.71K  31.9M   191M
    sda         -      -  1.94K  1.34K  9.03M  48.6M
    sdb         -      -  1.62K  1.45K  7.66M  48.5M
    sdc         -      -  1.62K  1.46K  7.66M  48.3M
    sdd         -      -  1.60K  1.45K  7.59M  45.5M
```

FIO

```
fio --ioengine=libaio --filename=tank --size=10G --time_based --name=fio --group_reporting --runtime=10 --direct=1 --sync=1 --iodepth=1 --rw=randrw --bs=1MB --numjobs=32
```

```
pool        alloc   free   read  write   read  write
----------  -----  -----  -----  -----  -----  -----
tank        1.34T  5.65T     14  27.5K  59.8K   940M
  raidz1    1.34T  5.65T     14  27.5K  59.8K   940M
    sda         -      -      5  7.14K  23.9K   235M
    sdb         -      -      1  7.02K  7.97K   235M
    sdc         -      -      4  7.97K  19.9K   235M
    sdd         -      -      1  5.33K  7.97K   235M
```

So it seems to me the zfs is working fine, it's just an interaction with PostgreSQL that's slow.

What settings have I played with

ZFS

```
recordsize = 16KB changed from 128KB
logbias = Latency , throughput preformed worse
compression = lz4 
primarycache = all , we have large write and reads
NO ARC or ZIL enabled
```

Postgres settings

```
full_page_writes=off
shared_buffers = 12GB
effective_cache_size = 12GB
maintenance_work_mem = 1GB
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.7
wal_buffers = 16MB
random_page_cost = 1.2
effective_io_concurrency = 200
work_mem = 256MB
min_wal_size = 1GB
max_wal_size = 2GB
max_worker_processes = 8
max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 4
max_parallel_workers = 8

and tried 
synchronous_commit = off , didn't see any performance increase
```

As a note **synchronous_commit** and **full_page_writes** I only did a Postgres config reload as this is a production site. I see some guys do restarts while some documentation states it only requires to reload. Reloads shows in psql if I **SHOW setting**.

At this point, I am a bit lost on what to try next. I am also unsure if the reload vs restart may be the reason I don't see the gains others are talking about.

As a side note. **Vacuum full analyze** didn't help either, not that I expected it to on a new copied table.

Thanks in advance for your help

**UPDATE 1**
I amended my fio commands as suggested by jjanes, Here are the outputs

First one is based on jjanes suggestion.

```
fio --ioengine=psync --filename=tank --size=10G --time_based --name=fio --group_reporting --runtime=10 --rw=rw --rwmixread=50 --bs=8KB 

fio: (g=0): rw=rw, bs=(R) 8192B-8192B, (W) 8192B-8192B, (T) 8192B-8192B, ioengine=psync, iodepth=1
fio-3.16
Starting 1 process
fio: Laying out IO file (1 file / 10240MiB)
Jobs: 1 (f=1): [M(1)][100.0%][r=91.6MiB/s,w=90.2MiB/s][r=11.7k,w=11.6k IOPS][eta 00m:00s]
fio: (groupid=0, jobs=1): err= 0: pid=3406394: Tue Dec 28 08:11:06 2021
  read: IOPS=16.5k, BW=129MiB/s (135MB/s)(1292MiB/10001msec)
    clat (usec): min=2, max=15165, avg=25.87, stdev=120.57
     lat (usec): min=2, max=15165, avg=25.94, stdev=120.57
    clat percentiles (usec):
     |  1.00th=[    3],  5.00th=[    4], 10.00th=[    4], 20.00th=[    4],
     | 30.00th=[    4], 40.00th=[    5], 50.00th=[    6], 60.00th=[    9],
     | 70.00th=[   43], 80.00th=[   48], 90.00th=[   57], 95.00th=[   68],
     | 99.00th=[  153], 99.50th=[  212], 99.90th=[  457], 99.95th=[  963],
     | 99.99th=[ 7504]
   bw (  KiB/s): min=49392, max=209248, per=99.76%, avg=131997.16, stdev=46361.80, samples=19
   iops        : min= 6174, max=26156, avg=16499.58, stdev=5795.23, samples=19
  write: IOPS=16.5k, BW=129MiB/s (135MB/s)(1291MiB/10001msec); 0 zone resets
    clat (usec): min=5, max=22574, avg=33.29, stdev=117.32
     lat (usec): min=5, max=22574, avg=33.40, stdev=117.32
    clat percentiles (usec):
     |  1.00th=[    7],  5.00th=[    8], 10.00th=[    8], 20.00th=[    9],
     | 30.00th=[   10], 40.00th=[   11], 50.00th=[   13], 60.00th=[   14],
     | 70.00th=[   17], 80.00th=[   22], 90.00th=[  113], 95.00th=[  133],
     | 99.00th=[  235], 99.50th=[  474], 99.90th=[ 1369], 99.95th=[ 2073],
     | 99.99th=[ 3720]
   bw (  KiB/s): min=49632, max=205664, per=99.88%, avg=132066.26, stdev=46268.55, samples=19
   iops        : min= 6204, max=25708, avg=16508.00, stdev=5783.26, samples=19
  lat (usec)   : 4=16.07%, 10=30.97%, 20=23.77%, 50=15.29%, 100=7.37%
  lat (usec)   : 250=5.94%, 500=0.30%, 750=0.10%, 1000=0.07%
  lat (msec)   : 2=0.08%, 4=0.03%, 10=0.01%, 20=0.01%, 50=0.01%
  cpu          : usr=3.47%, sys=72.13%, ctx=19573, majf=0, minf=28
  IO depths    : 1=100.0%, 2=0.0%, 4=0.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     submit    : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, 64=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     complete  : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, 64=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     issued rwts: total=165413,165306,0,0 short=0,0,0,0 dropped=0,0,0,0
     latency   : target=0, window=0, percentile=100.00%, depth=1

Run status group 0 (all jobs):
   READ: bw=129MiB/s (135MB/s), 129MiB/s-129MiB/s (135MB/s-135MB/s), io=1292MiB (1355MB), run=10001-10001msec
  WRITE: bw=129MiB/s (135MB/s), 129MiB/s-129MiB/s (135MB/s-135MB/s), io=1291MiB (1354MB), run=10001-10001msec
```

Second one is from https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/big-data-and-business-intelligence/9781785284335/1/ch01lvl1sec14/checking-iops

```
fio --ioengine=libaio --direct=1 --name=test_seq_mix_rw --filename=tank --bs=8k --iodepth=32 --size=10G --readwrite=rw --rwmixread=50

test_seq_mix_rw: (g=0): rw=rw, bs=(R) 8192B-8192B, (W) 8192B-8192B, (T) 8192B-8192B, ioengine=libaio, iodepth=32
fio-3.16
Starting 1 process
test_seq_mix_rw: Laying out IO file (1 file / 10240MiB)
Jobs: 1 (f=1): [M(1)][100.0%][r=158MiB/s,w=157MiB/s][r=20.3k,w=20.1k IOPS][eta 00m:00s] 
test_seq_mix_rw: (groupid=0, jobs=1): err= 0: pid=3484893: Tue Dec 28 08:13:31 2021
  read: IOPS=17.7k, BW=138MiB/s (145MB/s)(5122MiB/36990msec)
    slat (usec): min=2, max=33046, avg=31.73, stdev=95.75
    clat (nsec): min=1691, max=34831k, avg=878259.94, stdev=868723.61
     lat (usec): min=6, max=34860, avg=910.14, stdev=883.09
    clat percentiles (usec):
     |  1.00th=[  306],  5.00th=[  515], 10.00th=[  545], 20.00th=[  586],
     | 30.00th=[  619], 40.00th=[  652], 50.00th=[  693], 60.00th=[  742],
     | 70.00th=[  807], 80.00th=[  955], 90.00th=[ 1385], 95.00th=[ 1827],
     | 99.00th=[ 2933], 99.50th=[ 3851], 99.90th=[14877], 99.95th=[17433],
     | 99.99th=[23725]
   bw (  KiB/s): min=48368, max=205616, per=100.00%, avg=142130.51, stdev=34694.67, samples=73
   iops        : min= 6046, max=25702, avg=17766.29, stdev=4336.81, samples=73
  write: IOPS=17.7k, BW=138MiB/s (145MB/s)(5118MiB/36990msec); 0 zone resets
    slat (usec): min=6, max=18233, avg=22.24, stdev=85.73
    clat (usec): min=6, max=34848, avg=871.98, stdev=867.03
     lat (usec): min=15, max=34866, avg=894.36, stdev=898.46
    clat percentiles (usec):
     |  1.00th=[  302],  5.00th=[  515], 10.00th=[  545], 20.00th=[  578],
     | 30.00th=[  611], 40.00th=[  644], 50.00th=[  685], 60.00th=[  734],
     | 70.00th=[  807], 80.00th=[  955], 90.00th=[ 1385], 95.00th=[ 1811],
     | 99.00th=[ 2868], 99.50th=[ 3687], 99.90th=[15008], 99.95th=[17695],
     | 99.99th=[23987]
   bw (  KiB/s): min=47648, max=204688, per=100.00%, avg=142024.70, stdev=34363.25, samples=73
   iops        : min= 5956, max=25586, avg=17753.07, stdev=4295.39, samples=73
  lat (usec)   : 2=0.01%, 10=0.01%, 20=0.01%, 50=0.01%, 100=0.01%
  lat (usec)   : 250=0.16%, 500=3.61%, 750=58.52%, 1000=19.22%
  lat (msec)   : 2=14.79%, 4=3.25%, 10=0.25%, 20=0.19%, 50=0.02%
  cpu          : usr=4.36%, sys=85.41%, ctx=28323, majf=0, minf=447
  IO depths    : 1=0.1%, 2=0.1%, 4=0.1%, 8=0.1%, 16=0.1%, 32=100.0%, >=64=0.0%
     submit    : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, 64=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     complete  : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.1%, 64=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     issued rwts: total=655676,655044,0,0 short=0,0,0,0 dropped=0,0,0,0
     latency   : target=0, window=0, percentile=100.00%, depth=32

Run status group 0 (all jobs):
   READ: bw=138MiB/s (145MB/s), 138MiB/s-138MiB/s (145MB/s-145MB/s), io=5122MiB (5371MB), run=36990-36990msec
  WRITE: bw=138MiB/s (145MB/s), 138MiB/s-138MiB/s (145MB/s-145MB/s), io=5118MiB (5366MB), run=36990-36990msec
```

---

**Conclusions**

So it turns out the major issue for poor performance was write amplification. The below post has a good comment on this by Dunuin https://www.linuxbabe.com/mail-server/setup-basic-postfix-mail-sever-ubuntu

In short summary

- 4K writes where the primary writes for the alter command
- Adding dedicated SLOG helped
- Adding dedicated ARC helped
- Moving WAHL files to separate tanks helped
- Changing record size to 16Kb helped
- Disabling sync writes on WAHL helped.

One thing I didn't try was recompling Postgres in 32Kb pages. Based on what I have seen this could have a significant performance impact and is worth investigating if you are installing a new cluster.

Thanks to everyone for their input into this problem. Hope this info helps someone else.

Comment: It is pretty weird to run fio but not look at its output.  Anyway, you probably want ioengine=psync and bs=8kB to better emulate what PostgreSQL does.  But many of the other settings also seem wrong for this task, copying a large table would not be rw=randrw, and probably not jobs=32 either.  I don't know exactly what sync, direct, or iodepth do, but they also seem suspect.

Comment: Thanks for the response @jjanes. The fio was run to check if the zfs pool was performing poorly with a normal large file. I expect you are right on the 8KB bs and probably 8 jobs as that matches the Postgres workers settings on my server. I'll post the fio outputs in the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder how you created the zfs pool. Once I forgot the ashift=12 option when creating the zfs pool.

Maybe check this option with zdb. (https://charsiurice.wordpress.com/2016/05/30/checking-ashift-on-existing-pools/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Could you please quote the relevant code snippet to improve the answer?